# Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm creating a Rails app with Rails 3.1.3:

```
git init
git remote add heroku <my heroku repo>
git add .
git commit -a -m "First commit"
git push heroku master
```

Got:

```
Counting objects: 102, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (86/86), done.
Writing objects: 100% (102/102), 315.47 KiB, done.
Total 102 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

**-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected**

To git@heroku.com:electric-dusk-3217.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to <my heroku rep>
```

Comment: Have you tried running `heroku create [appname]`?

Comment: I've created app on the cedar stack: heroku create --stack cedar

Comment: What does this error actually mean?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem was that my "Gemfile" was named "gemfile"

Comment: @Whitecolor Had the exact same issue and your solution worked! Then ran into other complicated problems after. But thank you.

Comment: Not only did this happen for me, but in a non-obvious way. Working in OSX, even with a file called `Gemfile`, if I do `vi gemfile`, it opens my `Gemfile`, and then upon saving renames it to `gemfile` without warning!

Comment: I guess this is a good reason to set up a partition that distinguishes between uppercase and lowercase characters...

Comment: what's the "Gemfile" ? i have a html game and i want to push it in heroku. and i get the same error

Answer (score 154):

I had a similar problem, but with Django (incorrectly named "requirements.txt"). I think to generalize the other answers here, when you get this error it's because Heroku is missing some key file that it uses to identify your app (and its type).

- php: index.php
- python: requirements.txt
- ruby: Gemfile  *# note the capitalization*
- node: package.json

Comment: Found another answer to this problem here (re-initialize the git repo): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305370/rails-3-2-heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected

Comment: Friendly reminder: also have a Procfile, if running web app be sure there is a webservice enabled via Procfile pointing to correct script. Also be sure web dyno is turned on for app in Heroku admin. ```remote: ----->Discovering process types...Procfile declares types -> web``` is via my Procfile

Comment: Thanks, adding requirements.txt helped me! Please note that you should commit it (add it to the git repo) and then try to push again..

Answer (score 45):

I ran into this error message, but my problem was that my rails app was not in the root directory of my git repo.  After I moved the files into the root dir, everything worked.

Comment: That seems like a poor solution. Is there a proper way to push the app while its in a subdirectory?

Comment: I'm using [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). I had trouble installing so I used [this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603510/how-do-i-correctly-install-the-tools-in-gits-contrib-directory)

Comment: I had the same problem - I was just starting with the heroku getting started for RoR and encountered this issue. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: I kept checking the commandline and it was "correct" but then I noticed I was in /home/myapp/myapp... doh...

Comment: My case, too. I `git init` my app folder as git root directory then the push to heroku went through. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Heroku detects a supported app by looking for specific project files. To find the requirements for your language, [start here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart).

- For Node.js, you need a [`package.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs).
- For Python applications you need a [`requirements.txt`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python).
- etc.

Answer (score 22):

Not associated with a new app, but... I ran into this same error message after installing a custom BUILDPACK on heroku and then forgetting about it. The next time I went to deploy to heroku I saw:

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

The fix was to check:

```
 heroku config
```

And, there, I found a Var called `BUILDPACK_URL` which I had to unset with:

```
heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL
```

... and voila!

Answer (score 12):

Another cause: I was pushing master, while working on a non-master branch. My master branch didn't have requirements.txt.

I didn't want to push from master, but heroku only pays attention to the master branch. The solution was to push my local branch to heroku's master branch:

```
git push heroku local_branch:master
```

Comment: You are my hero  ! I spent hours try to find this ><

Answer (score 7):

Another cause of this error for Rails apps: we had this deploy error occur when we hadn't removed a git merge conflict from our Gemfile.lock file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. "Gemfile" was included in ".gitignore" and has therefore not been part of the deployment. Heroku requires Gemfile for Rails projects.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by making a superficial change to my Gemfile and recommitting. For some reason it wasn't included in my last commit.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem here. 
My check as follow:
1. Make sure "foreman start" works well locally.
2. Make sure only one new app create on your heroku account.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 3):

I was following the [RailsTutorial.org](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning) steps and this error showed up. None of the answers on this post worked. Then I saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected#comment27912117_13436954) that led to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11571284/3861396) which was the only thing that worked for me so that might solve other people's problems with the tutorial as well.

Comment: I think the cause is that I init the repo on parent directory of the RAIL_PROJECT directory. So make cedar can't recognize what type of the app is. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

When this problem appears with the project based on static files (only html, css and js) it is recommended to follow this guidlines:
https://discussion.heroku.com/t/push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected/640/3

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem with django based app. Everything seemed to be ok: file names and other settings.

The problem was that in heroku console there was a `BUILDPACK_URL` setting defined for `node.js` - thus django application was rejected.