# Pushing a Play app to Heroku results in "Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" error

Tags: java, git, heroku, playframework

I already pushed a Play app before, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error now on another app:

```
git push heroku master
...

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected) doesn't seem to be relevant, since I don't have a Gemfile (my other app pushes quite fine without one). At first I had a Procfile [as instructed here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play), but then I noticed my other working app does't have a Procfile, so I removed it.

Here is [the working app](https://github.com/ripper234/Whatever-Origin), and [the problematic one](https://github.com/ripper234/Bitcoin-Potato).

The remote git config is

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:bitcoinpotato.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

The app stack is the latest - [cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have an `application.conf` in the `conf` directory, which is what the Play! buildpack uses to identify the fact that the application is Play!

You can find the Heroku buildpack here:  https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play

Comment: Whoops, it was in my .gitignore, so never actually committed. Thanks!