# Rails 3.2: Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cedar

Rails newbie here. I'm trying to deploy my Rails 3.1/Ruby 1.9.3-p0 app to Heroku and have followed all the steps according to Heroku. But I keep running into:

Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

I've tried all the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected) but so far unsuccessful.

Comment: I realise I'm running ruby 1.9.3-p0 and followed the steps in http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html but hasn't helped so far. Could it be Heroku and their experimental support for 1.9.3?

Comment: No, I run a 1.9.3 app on heroku just fine. How did you create your app on heroku? Did you do: `heroku apps:create myapp --stack cedar` ?

Comment: Yes I ran `heroku create myapp --stack cedar`

Comment: OK I got it working although I wouldn't consider this a fix! I created another sample app with the same gemfile and deployed it to Heroku which worked fine. I then copied all files over from my other app to this new one and pushed it to the same heroku repo.. and it worked!

Answer (score 74):

I have encountered a similar rejection. What worked for me was reinitializing the .git file.

Try in the command line:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Reinitialize"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Before you take this drastic step, you might check that you're on the master branch. Heroku ignores non-master branches. If this is your issue, you can either switch to master and deploy from there, or push your non-master branch to heroku's master branch: `git push heroku branch_name:master`.

Comment: Great answer, but if you're using PowerShell like me, you'll want `rm -Recurse -Force .git`

Comment: I wouldn't jump straight to smashing your entire repository's history, branches, remotes, etc. Just breathe a minute before you do this.

Answer (score 8):

I Have just solved this problem with one of my apps. If you check the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support), the Cedar Stack searches for the Gemfile in the **root directory**. In my case, the root directory only had the folder containing my app with the Gemfile inside it.

So, what you need to do is to initialize a new git repo inside this folder and add the remote:

```
$ cd my_app_folder
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Heroku commit"
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:my-app-in-heroku.git
$ git push heroku master
```

And you're done!

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I encounter this error, I check the following two things:

- Make sure the Gemfile exist in **root directory** of Rails application. Heroku use it to determine what type of application to deploy.
- Make sure the Rails app **root directory** itself is put under version control (e.g: Git) rather than its parent directory.

If you accidentally put the parent directory of your rails application into version control. Delete the `.git` directory inside this parent directory and initialize a new repository but this time under the Rails application directory.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Change to something"
```

Then run

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Tried that and also did it again by cloning the repo into a new directory but still didn't work.

Comment: when you reinitialize your files for github. Were your files added to github and ready to be pushed?

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this issue a few time before and it was because I was trying to push a remote branch to heroku.

To solve the problem, instead of using:

```
git push heroku master
```

I used:

```
git push heroku my-branch:master
```

This pushes the remote branch `my-branch` in the git repository to the `master` branch of heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My file structure was not what heroku expected (.git must be on the same level as Gemfile). I removed the Rails_Code folder and it worked.

```
Project\
         .git
         Rails_Code\
                     Gemfile
                     etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Situation, Like @petwho said above

"Make sure the Gemfile exist in root directory of Rails application. Heroku use it to determine what type of application to deploy."

In my case, somehow my `Gemfiles` and `Gemfile.lock` was being ignored. When I checked on github there was no Gemfile being pushed up with my app due because `.gitignore` was ignoring my gemfiles.

After removing my gemfiles from gitignore, I pushed to heroku and everything worked smoothly