# Error on git push = ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I think, it's a different issue than this([remote rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542665/remote-rejected-master-master-pre-receive-hook-declined)), and many people are facing the same issue, So I am posting a new here.

My friend added me on bitbucket.org as an admin, so that I can help on his project. So, I wanted to start by taking a pull of the latest code on my local.

**Steps I followed:**

1. Goto empty folder
2. `git init`
3. `git remote -v` (this gives nothing)
4. `git remote add origin <path to git repo>`
5. `git remote add master <path to git repo>`
6. `git remote -v` (this show both with fetch and push in brackets)
7. `git fetch origin master`
8. `git pull origin master` (I have latest code now, all files and folders)
9. `touch test` (lets test a "test" commit)
10. `git status`
11. `git add .`
12. `git commit -m "testing, first commit"`
13. `git push origin master`

**error:**

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 274 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: permission denied to update branch master
To '<repo path>'
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '<repo path>'
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It looks like the branch management (one of the admin settings) in bitbucket has been configured to only allow certain people to push directly to master.

Try creating a branch - `git checkout -b test`, create your test commit and push `git push origin test:test`. You can always cleanly delete this branch once you have completed the test.

The other option (probably best agreeing with whoever set this up) is you go to `bitbucket` and head to admin, branch management and remove `master` be too limited. cf - https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Branch+management

Comment: I didnt add myself for push to branch. Thanks the other option worked for me.

Comment: Just add permission throught bitbucket WORked FOr Me

Comment: for me below command worked, git commit --amend --reset-author and then use git config user.email "Somnath.Kadam@domainname.com" 
git config user.name "Kadam, Somnath" and now git push origin master

Comment: Same error came to me for another branch. I had set "Write access" to "Nobody" in "branch permissions". Making it to "Everybody" resolved the issue for me.

Comment: In my case, I was a repository administrator. I was having the same problem until I added my individual account as having Write access to the branch. The Administrators group had Write access, but I hadn't been added there. After the main admin added me to the group, I didn't need the individual account. It sucks that I can mangle the repository configuration as an administrator multiple ways but I couldn't push source code changes as one.

Answer (score 4):

Just reporting another case leading to the specified error. If the Bitbucket repository size reaches 2 GB, Bitbucket itself restricts the repository to read-only access. 
When that happens, contributors with read/write permissions are not able to push and get the "pre-receive hook declined" error.

I also found these documents from Atlassian: 
https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/05/30/repository-size-limits/
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html

Links include a guide on how to restore the repo back to full functionality

Answer (score 2):

I have a better solution on Bitbucket:
If you are admin go to Repo >Settings >Limit Pushes section, and in "Branch name" put 'master', and in "..search... user" put your user name - then push "ADD" - and you are done :)

Answer (score 1):

I think package setuptools/distribute is listed in requirements.txt. Please remove the same.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue with me on gitlab, I asked the repo owner to grand me `maintainer` role and the issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario ->
I also had this issue and I also configured global parameters, tried branching etc but it didnt work for me.

Below was the issue -> I recently joined my current firm and till my Bitbucket credentials got activated, I was using someone elses credentials to access Jira, Bitbucket etc.
Now this credetials got saved in Windows inside "**Credential Manager**".
After deleting those other colleague credentials, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to force push on my ticket branch, and it was rejected.
Went to `Repository settings` -> `Hooks` -> found out that `Reject Force Push` was enabled, and disabled it.
Use at your own risk.

Answer (score -2):

**What worked for me was:**

1. Created a new branch locally
2. Bitbucket -> Settings -> Repository details = changed default branch (e.g to prod)
3. Bitbucket -> Branches -> delete master branch (you can do this without step 2)
4. Then push your locally created branch (e.g master)
5. Bitbucket -> Settings -> Repository details = changed default branch (e.g to master)