# bitbucket git cannot lock ref

Tags: git, bitbucket

Seems to be im having a nightmare i keep getting this error when i push

```
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': Unable to create '/data/c01/n01/p/vp0443/data/d-389/r-13803389/refs/heads/master.lock': File exists.
remote:
remote: If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
remote: git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
remote: process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
To https://sam_roberts_@bitbucket.org/sam_roberts_/admitme.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://sam_roberts_@bitbucket.org/sam_roberts_/admitme.git'
```

So far,

I've tried resetting git
ive followed this tutorial
[Error on git push = ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407962/error-on-git-push-remote-rejected-master-master-pre-receive-hook-decli)

i tried following this one too
[Failed to lock refs/heads/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228436/failed-to-lock-refs-heads-master)

any ideas??

Comment: Do what the error message suggests, delete `/data/c01/n01/p/vp0443/data/d-389/r-13803389/refs/heads/master.lock` and you should be good. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500089/fatal-unable-to-create-refs-heads-master-lock-file-exists-fatal-getting-t#26837305

Comment: That the issue, its remote and on bitbucket...

Comment: i dont have access to that file i dont think?

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I thought that would have been local for sure. Nice that you got it figured out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to this, contact bitbucket, They removed the lock file for me :D

Comment: mine is paid account.. why they lock for me ? i couldn't understand.