# Unable to push heroku master

Tags: railstutorial.org

i'm currently on section 1.4.2 of Mike Hartl's rails tutorial. When i try to push my project up to Heroku i get the following error:

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.10 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:agile-badlands-7756.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:agile-badlands-7756.git'
```

Here are the contents of my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Gem lock file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.5)
      actionpack (= 4.0.5)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.5)
      activemodel (= 4.0.5)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.5)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.2)
    builder (3.1.4)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.1.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.10)
    jbuilder (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    pg (0.15.1)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.5)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.5)
      actionpack (= 4.0.5)
      activerecord (= 4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.5)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.5)
      actionpack (= 4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.3.8)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    sprockets (2.12.1)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.1.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.39)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (= 4.0.1)
  jbuilder (= 1.0.2)
  jquery-rails (= 3.0.4)
  pg (= 0.15.1)
  rails (= 4.0.5)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  sass-rails (= 4.0.1)
  sdoc (= 0.3.20)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.8)
  turbolinks (= 1.1.1)
  uglifier (= 2.1.1)
```

Any ideas? This is my first post on stack so let me know if i need to add anything else! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remote rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542665/remote-rejected-master-master-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Comment: @user can you paste contents of your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: @uDay I added the Gem lock file to the description. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **gemlock.file**

Change the line with **i18n (0.6.10)** to **i18n (0.6.9)**

The reason is because there is no gem 0.6.10 - the most current one is 0.6.9

**Also**, don't forget to push up the changes by doing:

git add .

git commit -m 'Update Gemlock.file'

git push origin master