# Pushing to Heroku fails because it wont detect my app type/buildpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to push the first version of a Ruby on Rails app to Heroku.

When I run `git push heroku master` the errors I get are:

```
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching no buildpack
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp'
```

Since no buildpack was detected, I tried to set it manually. When I run `heroku buildpacks` I get `Buildpack URL heroku/ruby`, but I still get the same error.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542665/remote-rejected-master-master-pre-receive-hook-declined) solution and my gemfile is present, my ruby version in the gemfile is defined and my gemfile.lock has the railties gem.

Heroku logs just regurgitate the errors above so it wasn't helpful

Any suggestions for what else my be wrong?

Comment: Run `git ls-files | grep Gemfile` in your project. You should see `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` on separate lines without any paths before them. If you don't, you should [go back to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542665/remote-rejected-master-master-pre-receive-hook-declined) and review the accepted answer more closely.

Comment: They are on separate lines without any paths before them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try putting the putting ruby version number on top of the GemFile.

```
ruby '<your ruby version>'
```

the following line above should be at the top of gemfile. Also make sure you have Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files committed, those will be checked upon pushed to heroku servers.

Comment: I had it under the source originally. That solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Yep glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit the app to the Git Index?
The `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are probably indexed but not yet commited.

Comment: i pushed after committing to the index. Same errors in the end

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the rails project at the root. If it's not, Heroku will not know the entry point.

So this: `somefolder/my_rails_app` will not work.