# heroku push rejected no-cedar-supported app detected

Tags: windows, git, heroku

trying to deploy my app to heroku in windows 7. I tried:

see [Rails 3.2: Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305370/rails-3-2-heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Reinitialize"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

The last step does not work for me getting this error?:

```
push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "no Cedar-supported app" implies that what you pushed doesn't contain any code or files that lets Heroku recognise what kind of application you are pushing.

What is in the git repo that you're pushing?

For example, for a Ruby app,  [you need a Gemfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#general-support-activation).  The [other languages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/language-support) have similar requirements.

Here, it's fairly obvious.  You're pushing an empty git repo.  So it can't magically create an app or know what to do with it :-D