# unable to deploy rails 4 app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

I am getting the response below when I try to deploy my app to heroku

I have a Procfile with `'web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb'` 
I am using unicorn

```
hangman git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 252, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (168/168), done.
Writing objects: 100% (252/252), 375.50 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 252 (delta 73), reused 217 (delta 53)


 Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:calm-taiga-4375.git
[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:calm-taiga-4375.git'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305370/rails-3-2-heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected

Comment: I have looked at the suggested links but neither of them were able to resolve my problem. that is why I posted it

Comment: What do your logs from `heroku logs` show? You do have a `Gemfile` and a `Gemfile.lock`, correct? Are you using a custom buildpack?

Comment: to me `no app detected` means that you didn't commit all files from rails project.

Answer (score 0):

**Buildpack**

When you deploy to Heroku, it uses something called [`buildpacks`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to determine the type of application you're using

The `buildpacks` basically work by looking at your `git` repo (uses the [pre-receive](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook), identifying certain files which will determine the app type, and then deploying to your system.

Your error suggests to me the Heroku buildpack does not recognize your app, therefore it's throwing your error.

---

**Git**

As suggested in the comments, this can be fixed by ensuring your `.gitignore` file has not had a lot of irrelevant files added, and ensuring the likes of your Procfile & other files are secure

---

**Fix**

> 1. Ensure your app has no unconventional files
> 2. Make sure you've not put anything in `config/config.rb`, `config/environment.rb`, `config/application.rb`

I would personally remove *anything* which is not part of your Rails app (like `Procfile` etc) in order to get it working. Once working, then you can add one thing at a time before you find the one thing causing the issue