# How do I let Heroku Know I have a requirements.txt file

Tags: django, git, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django app on to Heroku but when I type `git push heroku master`, I get this output:

```
Counting objects: 1213, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (1184/1184), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1213/1213), 4.36 MiB | 504.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1213 (delta 449), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to article-django.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/article-django.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/article-django.git'
```

I created a `requirements.txt` file, as advised in [Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected) and I then typed in `pip install -r requirements.txt` before typing in `git push heroku master` again but I got the same output and so I need to know how to let Heroku know `requirements.txt` exists so I don't get this same error again.

Comment: Did you add `requirements.txt` to the repo?

Comment: I believe I did.  I did `git add requirements.txt`, unless that's not how you add files to a repo?

Comment: Did you commit the changes?

Comment: I committed the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I typed in `git commit -m 'another commit'` and I got this output:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'django/master'.
Untracked files:
    procfile
    requirements.txt
```

I then typed in these commands:

```
git add procfile
git add requirements.txt
```

I typed in `git commit -m 'another commit'` and then `git push heroku master`, which worked.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding the ~ files, they are backups created by your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but maybe you miss to add a [Procfile].(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) This file is neccesary to declare which server/process is going to run the dyno.

Comment: I added this procfile: `web: gunicorn django_test.wsgi` but when I tried `git push heroku master` after that, I got the same error message. How do I let Heroku know the procfile exists?

Comment: In this case I have no idea, maybe you can try http://stackoverflow.com/a/11571284/263989