# Deploy Rails app to Heroku detect app matching no buildpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, buildpack

This might be a duplicate however, I could not fix it from those answers so any help will be appreciated.

**Error**
`Failed to detect app matching no buildpack`

After creating the Heroku app I set my buildpack (same error comes with `heroku/ruby` buildpack)

`heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git`

`Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are in the root folder.

Added ruby version and `rails_12factor gem` to Gem file.

`PostgreSQL` set to production.

```
ruby "2.3.0"
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production, :test do
  gem 'pg'
end


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'kaminari'
gem 'soundcloud'
gem 'redis'
gem 'yt', '~> 0.28.0'


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

**.gitignore**

```
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp

*.DS_Store
```

Comment: Could you show your Gemfile?

Comment: you shouldn't manually need to use the ruby buildpack, it can detect it. Is your rails app at the root of the repo?

Comment: @maxple yes, my app is at root 

`Gemfile  README.rdoc app  config  db  log  test  vendor
Gemfile.lock Rakefile bin  config.ru lib  public  tmp`

Comment: @Nicholas did you commit everything in git?

Comment: If I remove the buildpack the following error shows 

`No default language could be detected for this app.` - that lead me to set manually the buildpack

Comment: @maxples, yes everything is committed and ready to be pushed.

Comment: Do you have `.gitignore` or `.slugignore` files? And maybe `Gemfile` in any of those files?

Comment: @michal I do have a `.gitignore` file, however GemFile is not included there. I updated the post with the `.gitignore` file

Comment: Thank you for your time by [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305370/rails-3-2-heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected) worked for me. 

Reinitialising the repository worked LOL

Comment: If you'd like to mark a question as solved, please do it in the answer box below, not as edits to the question. We have a tick/acceptance system in place, so we don't use [solved] title devices.

Comment: @halfer, thank you, I will do the edits.