# How can I debug my failure to push my Perloku app to Heroku?

Tags: perl, git, heroku, github

I'm experimenting with using Heroku for Perl, but this question is not specific to Perl.

```
[root@myhost MyApp-Perl]# git push heroku master
Pushing to git@heroku.com:MyApp-perl.git
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 1.70 KiB, done.
Total 17 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Fetching custom buildpack... done
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:MyApp-perl.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:MyApp-perl.git'
```

Comment: Others on SO have experienced this symptom. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there could be many causes for this error. Here are a few guesses:

1. Are you pushing from the right branch? Heroku looks for code in the 'master' branch. From ["Heroku Dev Center | Deploying With Git"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying_code):

> "Branches pushed to Heroku other than master will be ignored... If
>   you’re working out of another branch locally, you can either merge to
>   master before pushing, or specify that you want to push your local
>   branch to a remote master. To push a branch other than master, use
>   this syntax:
>
> $ git push heroku yourbranch:master"
>
> Are all of the required files committed into your git depo? Each of the languages and frameworks on the [Getting Started articles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart) have certain requirements for deploying them on heroku. For example, [Ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby) requires a gemfile and either a config.ru or Procfile. [Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python) requires a Procfile and a requirements.txt. If you are missing any of the required files heroku will not detect a valid cedar app.
>
> It looks like you're using [Perloku](https://github.com/judofyr/perloku)? If so, do you have a Makefile.PL in your git depo? Do you have an executable file called 'Perloku'? What custom buildpack are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, I finally solved it. It's probably because you're running on windows. The script need to be changed to executable.

Please check https://github.com/judofyr/perloku/issues/6