# How do I correctly install the tools in git's contrib directory?

Tags: git

Git includes a [set of tools contributed by third parties](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib). I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use these tools correctly.

For example, I'd like to use [git-subtree](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree). There seem to be a number of ways I could use this:

1. **Copy to my path**

   ```
    cp /path/to/git-subtree.sh /usr/local/bin/git-subtree
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-subtree
   ```

   Works fine, feels a bit hacky.
2. **Symlink to my path**

   ```
    chmod +x /path/to/git-subtree.sh
    ln -s /path/to/git-subtree.sh /usr/local/bin/git-subtree
   ```

   Also works, feels marginally less hacky
3. **Use a git alias**

   Add the following to my global .gitconfig file:

   ```
    [alias]
        subtree = !/path/to/git-subtree.sh
   ```

   Then good old chmod again:

   ```
    chmod +x /path/to/git-subtree.sh
   ```

   Works, feels all nice and git-ish.
4. **Use the Makefile**

   Per the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/INSTALL).

   ```
    cd /path/to/git-subtree.sh
    make
    make install
    make install-doc
   ```

   Doesn't work for me, it tries to install to a non-existent path. Perhaps this is because I installed git using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) rather than installing from source? I'm too lazy to investigate; I already have three working alternatives. :)

So my question is, which of these is the preferred way of installing git-contrib add-ons? Is there even a preferred way? Is there another option I haven't suggested that's better than the ones listed above?

Comment: You can also just point your `PATH` variable to the git-contrib stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contribs is a collection of helpful things. You don't install them as a package. For example, to install the tab completion, you simply source that script from your .bash_profile script. Each contrib in that folder has it's own way of using it.

as for compiling git from source

```
make
sudo make install
```

after you install all the prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks Adam, makes sense. It's OK, I know how to install git from source, I'm just too lazy to do so. :)

Comment: it's so simple that lazy is no excuse! :P

Answer (score 10):

from git/contrib/git-subtree:

> HOW TO INSTALL git-subtree
>      ==========================
>
> First, build from the top source directory.
>
> Then, in contrib/subtree, run:
>
> ```
>  make
>  make install
>  make install-doc
> ```
>
> If you used configure to do the main build the git-subtree build will
>      pick up those settings.  If not, you will likely have to provide a
>      value for prefix:
>
> ```
>  make prefix=<some dir>
>  make prefix=<some dir> install
>  make prefix=<some dir> install-doc
> ```
>
> To run tests first copy git-subtree to the main build area so the
>      newly-built git can find it:
>
> ```
>  cp git-subtree ../..
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
>  make test
> ```

I just verified that this works:

1. downloaded source via existing git
2. installed build deps

   ```
   $ apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev
   ```
3. check out the latest release branch and build

   ```
   $ git co v1.7.11.3  
   $ make prefix=/usr/local all  
   $ sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
   ```
4. build and install contrib/subtree

   ```
   $ cd contrib/subtree  
   $ make  
   $ make install  
   $ make install-doc
   ```
5. verify it all works

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/git  
   [todd@montreal-01 subtree ((v1.7.11.3))]$ git --version  
   git version 1.7.11.3
   ```

Check, we have the latest git.

```
[todd@montreal-01 subtree ((v1.7.11.3))]$ git subtree  
usage: git subtree add   --prefix=<prefix> <commit>  
    or: git subtree merge --prefix=<prefix> <commit>  
    or: git subtree pull  --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <refspec...>  
    or: git subtree push  --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <refspec...>  
    or: git subtree split --prefix=<prefix> <commit...>

    -h, --help            show the help  
    -q                    quiet  
    -d                    show debug messages  
    -P, --prefix ...      the name of the subdir to split out  
    -m, --message ...     use the given message as the commit message for the merge commit  

options for 'split'  
    --annotate ...        add a prefix to commit message of new commits  
    -b, --branch ...      create a new branch from the split subtree  
    --ignore-joins        ignore prior --rejoin commits  
    --onto ...            try connecting new tree to an existing one  
    --rejoin              merge the new branch back into HEAD  

options for 'add', 'merge', 'pull' and 'push'  
    --squash              merge subtree changes as a single commit
```

Check, we have subtree working.

Comment: it works! thanks. this was key: `make prefix=/usr/local all` ..I'd previously done a vanilla make install of git and the subtree install was failing. One small omission: I was missing an additional dependency `asciidoc` when doing `make install-doc` for subtree.

Comment: Also, when not reading your description of the install process, it is unclear from the git docs whether to install and build the subtree contrib project before the git project.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you already have (the latest version of) git installed why do you need to compile from scratch to use something in contribs?

Answer (score 8):

Here's the simplest thing that worked for me, installing git-subtree on Ubuntu 12.10:

Get the code

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git --depth=1
cd git/contrib/subtree
make
```

"Install" it into the git tools directory

```
sudo cp git-subtree /usr/lib/git-core/
```

For the man page, you need asciidoc which is not a small installation, but if you have it:

```
make doc
gzip git-subtree.1
sudo cp git-subtree.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1
```

And that's it.

Comment: Works like a charm (at least on Ubuntu). Much simplier, provided one already has git installed - no need to `make` and `make install` entire git from source. Plus - nice to have a man page!

Answer (score 2):

All of this looks a bit more complex than necessary ..
(maybe because the install.sh is a recent addition?)
This is what worked for me. Or so it seems.

```
# go to a directory where it's ok to put temporary stuff
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree.git
cd git-subtree/
# shell script does the job for you.
sudo sh ./install.sh
cd ..
# remove the git cloned stuff, now that all relevant things have been copied (we hope)
rm -r git-subtree

# test that it works
git subtree
# should print some help/usage stuff.
```

There is an instruction saying mostly just that:
https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/INSTALL

I am a bit more stupid than that. I need to be told that I have to download (git clone) the thing to an *arbitrary location* before I run the shell script, and that this stuff can be disposed afterwards.

The contents of the install.sh are quite revealing,
https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/install.sh
If you ever want to install a git thingie that doesn't provide an install.sh of its own, this could be a place to start.

Comment: my answer may be stupid concerning this.. https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/THIS-REPO-IS-OBSOLETE

Comment: it appears that the latest git where this is available (1.7.11 and up)  is not easily available on Debian yet. The latest you get with apt-get is 1.7.10. So this repo might not be so pointless after all.

Comment: It appears to me to be a not so bad idea, provided I didn't find any other solution for standard Windows Git Bash, which comes without make. Installing it with `cp git-subtree.sh "$(git --exec-path)"/git-subtree` seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

## All of the below in one command, tested in Ubuntu only:

```
curl -L https://gist.githubusercontent.com/haf/3426227/raw/a719a28d65478fad8994931b7514d12cce9717c2/install-git.sh | bash
```

## Now, here's how to install latest git with git as a package in ubuntu

To do it as a package (preferrable):

```
sudo apt-get remove git -y
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev asciidoc
```

If you don't install asciidoc, ignore the line with make target 'install-doc', below.

This will checkout the master/latest tagged release and install it with [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) as a package.

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
cd git
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=git make prefix=/usr/local install
```

then the contrib:

```
cd contrib/subtree
make prefix=/usr/local
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=git-subtree make prefix=/usr/local install
```

...answer `yes` or `y` to the question whether to exclude the files from the home folder.

```
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=git-subtree-doc make prefix=/usr/local install-doc
```

...answer `yes` or `y` to the question whether to exclude the files from the home folder.

You can now handle the git package:

```
dpkg -r git
```

and the subtree package:

```
dpkg -r git-subtree
dpkg -r git-subtree-doc
```

If you don't feel like having half a gigabyte of latex perl scripts hogging harddrive space afterwards:

```
sudo apt-get remove asciidoc -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

**Or** all of it (all build deps)

```
sudo apt-get remove -y libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev asciidoc
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

Thanks to @toddg for the basic commands that I needed!

I haven't been able to make `git subtree --help` look up the correct man page yet.

Comment: This method caused problems with regards to the git-man, git-core, and gitk packages, and made it impossible to install git-cola without "upgrading" git back to the old version.

Comment: I have had problems with it too. If you have have solutions I'm happy to update the post.

Comment: First, you need to add `apt-get remove git-man` to the beginning of the instructions. Then, I suppose using checkinstall to provide fake git-man, git-core and gitk packages would improve matters. You probably need to specify a high enough version number to checkinstall that would prevent apt from "upgrading" the package. I gave up before trying all that and ended up doing what my answer describes.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this in this day and age, the URL to curl is `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/haf/3426227/raw/a719a28d65478fad8994931b7514d12cce9717c2/install-git.sh`