# "Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" when trying to upload a Sinatra app with an existing git repo

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, sinatra

I have an existing git repo for my personal website, which I am porting to Sinatra (mainly for templating, it's a static site). I do NOT want to lose/reset this git repository.

When I try to push to Heroku, I get the error below. I have a config.ru file, a Gemfile, and a Gemfile.lock, along with some other stuff for Sinatra. Running `rackup` works, running `bundle exec rackup` works, and I didn't get any warnings from Heroku about missing dependencies.

Am I missing something? I can post the directory structure of my site if it would help (though it's close sourced).

```
~/Repos/website ➜ gp heroku master
Counting objects: 2836, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2669/2669), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2836/2836), 3.48 MiB | 252 KiB/s, done.
Total 2836 (delta 481), reused 2117 (delta 155)

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:APP_NAME_HERE.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:APP_NAME_HERE.git'
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your config.ru?

Comment: Similar question, might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected

Comment: @elithrar https://gist.github.com/db20b819d1f06b5a3867 (it's extremely simple, as I'm new to Sinatra)

Comment: @Kashyap Thanks, but I already reviewed that. I tried every answer mentioned on that question's page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. I was working on a git branch especially for Heroku/Sinatra support, and it turns out I was running `git push heroku master`, which pushed local master to remote master. The master branch did not have a valid Heroku app. I assumed it would push the current local branch to the remote master branch, which is not the case. `git push sinatra:master` solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

A Cedar app *should* recognise the `config.ru` file and create a web process for you, so it's possible that some essential file is not tracked by git.  Check that `config.ru`, `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are all committed (you can use `git status`, but note that it will not output anything for ignored files so you should also check your `.gitignore` file).

If all the files are committed, you could also try specifying the command you want the web process to use in a `Procfile`.  See the Heroku docs for more information:

- [Getting started with Ruby: Declare process types with Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby#declare-process-types-with-procfile)
- [Declaring and Scaling Process Types with Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Comment: Those files are existing and committed. I looked at those articles on the Profile, and created one with the contents `web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT`. Heroku still gives me the same error when I push, and running `foreman start` locally results in this error: https://gist.github.com/c8957f5323adf82d0b96. Adding `gem 'bundler', '>= 1.0.0'` to my Gemfile did not fix the issue either.

Comment: Note the `config.ru` must be in your root directory, not in a subdirectory.  Where is it?

Comment: The root directory of my app/repo, correct? If so, it's there.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git ls-files` somewhere?

Comment: Good idea, done. I cut some of the output out at points mainly for brevity (where there were tons of image files). https://gist.github.com/82e8aa571727ca07a34c

Comment: Your file list looks good to me.  I suggest you talk to Heroku support, their IRC channel has proved useful to me in the past.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can get free official support there? I'm new to Heroku, and plan to stay in the free tier for a while. Also, where is the channel? "heroku" on freenode?

Answer (score 2):

For those who find that the accepted answer doesn't solve their problem, this related question may provide the solution: ["Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" when trying to upload a Sinatra app with an existing git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082116/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected-when-trying-to-upload-a)