# Heroku Core Data buildpack, no cedar supported app detected

Tags: ios, heroku, afincrementalstore

I'm attempting to migrate an existing Core Data (with local store) project to Heroku using [AFIncrementalStore and the Core Data Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app), but pushing to Heroku keeps failing.

The primary differences between my app setup and that in the aforelinked tutorial:

- I've set up the Xcode workspace with the AFNetworking/AFIncremental dependencies, but not actually changed any code yet.
- The directory containing the Xcode project/workspace files is one level down from the root of my git repo. This means `heroku create --buildpack git://github.com/mattt/heroku-buildpack-core-data.git` fails to create the git remote named `heroku`, but I can `cd ..` and `heroku git:remote -a appname` and that seems to be cool.
- I'm working on a branch other than `master` in my git repo, so when I push to Heroku I need to use `git push heroku my_local_branch:master`.

However, that `git push` doesn't get anywhere, not even into the Core Data Buildpack stuff (as far as I can tell):

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:appname.git
 ! [remote rejected] my_local_branch -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12086925/334934

Comment: AFAICT, those and most of the other answers for questions involving this error require certain files from a Rails (or PHP, or whatever) app to *already exist* in the repo I'm pushing to Heroku. The Core Data buildpack, on the other hand, is apparently supposed to *create* them. But it looks like it doesn't get to that point before this error comes up, because otherwise we'd see some of the logging from [the buildpack scripts](https://github.com/mattt/heroku-buildpack-core-data/blob/master/bin/compile).

Answer (score 1):

I just went through one of my projects and arranged it to mimic yours.

The buildpack will fail if the `.xcdatamodeld` isn't within 1 folder level of root. I suggest [filing an issue on Github](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-core-data/issues/new).

Comment: Yup. Moving my model up a level worked; issues filed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you created the Heroku app, maybe you didn't pass in the `--buildpack` parameter. You can check by running `heroku config` and verify there's a `BUILDPACK_URL` setting pointing at the buildpack repo. If that's missing, you can add it:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/some/buildpack.git -a myapp
```

Documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks).

Comment: Nope. It echoed `BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/mattt/heroku-buildpack-core-data.git` when I ran `heroku create ...`, and shows it when I check `heroku config`.

Comment: Hm, does your source code match what's looked for in the detect script? https://github.com/mattt/heroku-buildpack-core-data/blob/master/bin/detect

Comment: Yes... sort of. It does have an `xcdatamodel` somewhere inside, though I don't trust that `ls $1/**/*.xcdatamodel*` will work for finding it. (Isn't `**` only available on versions of `bash` newer than ship with OS X 10.8.x?) However, if this test were failing, I should be seeing the error from that script, "No Core Data model detected", not (or before) "no Cedar-supported app detected", right?