# Can't push PHP application to heroku

Tags: php, git, heroku

I'm having trouble pushing my PHP project to Heroku. Every time I try to push I get this error:

```
----> Heroku receiving push
 !    Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected.

To git@heroku.com:intense-hamlet-7552.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:intense-hamlet-7552.git'
```

It's my first time using Heroku, so here's what I've done (tried to follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)) :

1. I've created a new folder in my Eclipse workspace.
2. In this folder I've run `git init`.
3. I created a new PHP project (in Eclipse) in this folder.
4. I run `heroku create`.
5. I commit  my files with TortoiseGit (I've also tried with the command-line, no difference).
6. I push the repository with `git push heroku master`
7. Then I get the error described above.

I've tried several times with new folders, new repositories but it happens every time.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** For people suggesting duplicated post:

I've seen the post [Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected) which describes a problem for a Ruby application, where a `Gemfile` is miss-spelled. My application is a PHP application and does not have a `Gemfile`.

Comment: Edited the post and described why it isn't a duplicate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured, that Heroku didn't regonize my application as a PHP app. I created an `index.php` with a hello world script, and boom! Everything worked.