# rails 2 on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stack, cedar

I've create an app on my local MAC MINI machine in Rails 2.2.2 with Webrick it works

Now I want upload the app on Heroku

**$ heroku create myapponline --stack cedar**

ok, and after I check if I exist the app on heroku

**$ git remote -v**

```
> heroku    git@heroku.com:myapponline.git (fetch)
> heroku    git@heroku.com:myapponline.git (push)
```

Great!

but when I want upload the app

**$ git push heroku master**

```
> Counting objects: 124, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (110/110), done. Writing objects: 100%
> (124/124), 75.90 KiB, done. Total 124 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
> 
> -----> Heroku receiving push  !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
> 
> To git@heroku.com:myapponline.git  ! [remote rejected] master ->
> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to
> 'git@heroku.com:myapponline.git'
```

NOTE when I digit **$ git status** all files are in the **master branch**

thank you in advance,

A

Answer (score 2):

Rails 2.2 is pre-Rack and pre-Bundler, so the normal Rails buildpack won't help you. It's possible, but honestly, you really need to upgrade. There are security implications with running old Rails versions (including 2.2.2 instead of 2.2.3), not to mention the fact that tying yourself to an ancient framework means it'll be difficult to take advantage of the last **three years** of work in the Ruby ecosystem.

If, after all that, you still have to do this for some reason, fine. You'll need to make your own [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) spinning up your web server of choice (Webrick? yuck!) on the Heroku-specified port. You'll also need some way of getting all your gems into the slug, either by [making a custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api) or by hacking Bundler into Ruby 2.2.

And yes, all of that require more Ruby knowledge than upgrading to a reasonable version of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

Describes a similar problem..