# Heroku Push Rejected for Rails 2.3.5

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to push my app up to Heroku, but am getting rejected. Here is the error message I'm getting.

```
Counting objects: 63, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 80.06 KiB, done.
Total 63 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:agile-shelf-2850.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:agile-shelf-2850.git'
```

My app is the simple hello world app and I am using the following:

Rails 2.3.5
Ruby 1.8.7
Gems 1.4.2

I've research the site and found others that have this problem but they are using Rails 3. Example: [Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

Any ideas? I'm using these older versions as the project i'm trying to integrate into is using these versions so i'm trying to stay consistent.

Comment: What files are in the root of your repository? A `Gemfile` indicates to Heroku that you're a Ruby app, a `config.ru` indicates you use Rack, and `config/environment.rb` with no `config/application.rb` indicates Rails 2.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I don't a config.ru, nor do I have a Gemfile. I also do not have config.ru. I do have a config/environment.rb with no config/application.rb so I do believe that my hello world app is Rails 2.

Comment: You need both a `Gemfile` and a `config.ru`. How did you end up with a Rails 2.3 application that doesn't have these files?

Comment: Try running ```bundle install```.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your config.gem lines in your config/environment.rb to a Gemfile and install bundler. Rails 2.x does not have inherent support of Bundler and Cedar requires that you use Bundler to specify your app's gem dependencies. Otherwise it will not see your app as a Rails app.

Install Bundler for Rails 2.3 via:

> http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rails23.html

If you have further problems afterwards let us know!