# Push rejected no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: git, heroku

I have just signed up on heroku and trying to add a first, single static html page to the app.  I followed the exact procedure to clone the repo and now trying to add the file, but keep getting this message:

```
 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:pak-attacks.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:my-project-saif.git'
```

Anyone has any idea about what is happening or what needs to be done? Many thanks.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/a/13436954/6309 wouldn't help?

Comment: but i don't have any gem file.. i only have a html page that i want to push. Do i need a gemfile?

Comment: No, I meant more in the general idea of the linked answer: "I think to generalize the other answers here, when you get this error it's because Heroku is missing some key file that it uses to identify your app (and its type)". Not sure about the specific missing file in your case though.

Answer (score 6):

Rename your static file to index.php - it will then be detected as a PHP application and will work fine - even if you're not using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem while pushing my rails project to heroku.

until I tried to use the following command to create in heroku, then succeed!!!  You should try this as well.

"heroku create --stack cedar"