# Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected (different issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have skimmed through almost all the question relating to this rejection. The one I come closest to my solution is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected).

But, the difference is that **I actually DO have Gemfile spelled correctly** for Heroku to understand my type of project.

So here is my situation, I am trying to push my rails project to heroku, I have all my files normal and running fine locally. However, I have it on Github already. Following [this instruction](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), I push my code to heroku. Then it gave me this:

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 228 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:arcane-chamber-1013.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:arcane-chamber-1013.git'
```

Has anyone experienced the same type of issue? May you please help on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Are you push a branch or master?

Is your Gemfile spelled like that, and in the root directory?

This error message occurs when Heroku can't determine which of the default supported languages your app is written in - which usually only ever occurs when it's missing some critical file.  Ruby apps use the [Gemfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#activation).

Comment: Thanks for the reply first of all. But I am sure it is spelled correctly. However, I think my case has a pre-condition that it originally was a git file that belongs to the project manager in my group. But he had problem installing the bundle. So just being a backup solution, I was asked to upload our mockup project on heroku. Then I failed to do so. Now I am questioning if it has anything to do with the fact that I am not the owner of the original git.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are actualy not pushing the code to heroku.

Make sure you have committed your code.

Comment: So here is what I did: I made some superficial changes to Gemfile, and then I commit it, then try to push it to heroku. Then I get the error codes above. I wonder if it is a conflict between branches?

Comment: But I couldnt find a solution anywhere