# Can't overwrite heroku master git repo

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to change the git repo that my Heroku app pushes from (previously a multi build pack), but I get the error:

```
> git push -f heroku master
> Fetching repository, done. Counting objects: 4111, done. Delta
> compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing objects: 100%
> (3868/3868), done. Writing objects: 100% (4111/4111), 39.41 MiB |
> 579.00 KiB/s, done. Total 4111 (delta 710), reused 0 (delta 0)
> 
> -----> Removing .DS_Store files
> -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
> 
>  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
> 
> To git@heroku.com:in2u.git  ! [remote rejected] master -> master
> (pre-receive hook declined)
```

What's weird is that this error only makes sense if heroku is actually being pushed the old contents of in2u.git, but I'm TELLING it to push from my local to the heroku remote.

Nothing in this SO post seemed to apply:

> [Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's in your local repository? Also, note that `origin` is not the same as where you're pushing from.

Comment: I mispoke - local! Thanks for spotting that. I updated the question. Local contains the new app file I want to push. It's not a custom buildpack (but the existing in2u.git was).

Comment: Maybe you need to blank out the `BUILDPACK_URL` setting from your heroku config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to blank out the `BUILDPACK_URL` setting from your Heroku config, to avoid it continuing to pull a custom buildpack. Heroku config isn't part of the repository, so just pushing from a clean repository won't remove it.