# How do I ADD the pg gem in the production environment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am new to programming and using RAILS on Cloud9 IDE. I am having difficulty trying to push my app into Heroku. I get the error:...

```
Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:
```

**NOTE:** The tutorial I am following tells me at Heroku setup section:

> Heroku uses the PostgreSQL database (pronounced “post-gres-cue-ell”,
>   and often called “Postgres” for short), which means that we need to
>   add the pg gem in the production environment to allow Rails to talk to
>   Postgres:17
>
> ```
>  group :production do   
>     gem 'pg', '0.17.1'   
>     gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2’ 
>  end
> ```

Question: How do I ADD the `pg` gem in the production environment (I suspect that the push rejected error is due to this)

Comment: This should help with the `push rejected...` issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected

Comment: Can you show us what's in your Gemfile?

Comment: Can I post a screen shot on here>?

Comment: Just copy and paste it?

Answer (score 5):

There should be a file in your application called `Gemfile`

open it up and add:

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
 gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

save the file, commit and try again.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean add this text direct into the file itself at the bottom or inputed through the Command Line

Comment: It says cannot find Gemfile. Yet the Gemfile is opened with the group :production do
 gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
 gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2’
end

Answer (score 1):

In your `Gemfile`

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and also remove `gem 'sqlite3'` **OR**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Because heroku can't install the sqlite3 gem. But you can tell bundler that it shouldn't be trying to except when developing.

Then run bundle install and try to deploy on Heroku.

Comment: Obliged will try this out. Can you advise why the 'sqlite3" should be removed. This is not in the tutorial.

Comment: SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk. While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least once every 24 hours.

Comment: appreciate this. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris : Hope this will help full for you, Please up vote my answer.

Comment: Why you are not up voting my answer?

Comment: It says that It can not find the Gemfile

Comment: On heroku or your local system?

Comment: on my local system (the cloud IDE)

Comment: Make sure you are in your project directory from command prompt.

Comment: If you are in your project directory through command prompt then run `bundle install`.