# Deploy Java application on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Java application on Heroku (this is the first time I try deploy on Heroku) and I'm following [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#deploy-the-app).
When I try to push my git repo with `git push heroku master` I get this error message:

[image]

Comment: google/SO is full of answers already when searching for 'heroku push rejected no cedar-supported app detected git' generally you might push on master while working on non master branch or procfile is missing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

Comment: @MatthewSainsbury  I've already seen that answer but I didn't find the solution. I've tried to deploy a Rails application and it gave me the same error and I solved it changing my Gemfile but now I'm trying to deploy a Java application and I don't know what to change in my java application folder.

Comment: are you basing this off the default java buildpack?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have anything checked into Git, or your git repo is based one directory up from your actual code.

Your `pom.xml` file should be in the root directory of your Git repository. This error actually means that it didn't find a `pom.xml` or any other file that indicates a "supported" app.

To verify your repo, run `git ls-files` and you should see the `pom.xml`.