# Git Push Error to Heroku, simple JavaScript files

Tags: git, heroku, github

I try to integrate JS into a new site. Everything is up to date in the master, and the `composer.json` and `index.php` files are correct. I have a separate /js folder with some simple JavaScript.

** Why are there problems with the Heroku push? **

`Mark$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 972 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to thawing-plateau-2867.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/thawing-plateau-2867.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/thawing-plateau-2867.git'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361475/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

Comment: My `index.php` file is correct. Why else is this problem still occuring?

Comment: The answer is farther down. Check the spelling/capitalization of your gemfile

Comment: It wasn't the gemfile or my index.php. After I merged my branches, I wasn't pulling from my master branch. Then I needed to push up to Heroku.